# How to install RQDA version in R version 4.02?

Tags: r, rqda

How to install RQDA version in R version 4.02?
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘RQDA’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 4.0.2)

Comment: I tried to use code if (!requireNamespace("devtools"))
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("Ronggui/RQDA") But R answered me Skipping 1 packages not available: gWidgetsRGtk2
Installing 11 packages: vctrs, bit, plogr, DBI, blob, bit64, gWidgets, igraph, RGtk2, gWidgetsRGtk2, RSQLite
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/Ольга/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Ошибка: Failed to install 'RQDA' from GitHub:
  (конвертировано из предупреждения) package ‘gWidgetsRGtk2’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the fork at https://github.com/RQDA/RQDA. Since packages that RQDA rely on have been archived on CRAN (RGtk and GtkWidgets), RQDA was archived subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

The official published package has been archived, because of some of its dependencies. However, the package can still be installed from the archives. The steps to do this are as follows:

1. Install RGtk2 from CRAN.
2. Install the archived versions of *gWidgets* and *gWidgetsRGtk2*. `devtools::install_version` can do this quite easily when the right arguments are passed to the function. Consult the help file.
3. Call `library(RGtk2)` at the R console. You will be prompted to install the GUI library **Gtk+**, if you don't already have it.
4. Install the archived version of RQDA from CRAN. If you are using a 64-bit system, you will have to pass the `--no-multiarch` flag, or else it will fail.
5. Launch RQDA with `library(RQDA)`.

I have used these steps to successfully install the package on Windows 10 64-bit running R-4.0.3. Others have used a similar algorithm to do it on Linux and Mac with only slight variations.

Since I had to replicate this for some members of my team I wrote an [R script](https://gist.github.com/BroVic/7771e1e86df35f6410a3f586ea1ef6c6) that can be used to carry out the installation. You are welcome to try it out.

That said, development on the main RQDA branch has recommenced, so I expect a resolution of this issue in the near future.